# Can you perfectly control electric currents' behavior in anisotropic media?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, material-science, biophysics

I'm an undergrad who is learning recently about anisotropy w.r.t. E&M. I understand that in anisotropic media the behavior of electric currents and other E&M aspects can be very unpredictable because of variable density, different materials throughout the medium possibly, etc. I know that methods like Finite Element Analysis are used to solve the PDEs and simplify the problem s.t. the behavior can be simulated and accurate predictions made.

For reference, the context for me is biophysics, so the anisotropic medium here could be biological tissues. For example I was reading about optogenetics (controlling neurons with light) and also this method of brain stimulation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation wherein a magnetic field is applied to the scalp which induces a current in nearby brain regions. The brain and other biological tissue obviously have lots of nanostructures and are anisotropic. Hence these methods are not 'precise' because for optogenetics for example, there is light scattering and shallow penetration. Same for the magnetic field method (TMS), the current's path can be hard to predict due to anisotropy. My question is however, even if you knew how the current would behave, does that actually help you control the current? In other words, let's say you could perfectly predict the behavior of the current and you also understood all the properties of the medium you are modeling (it is basically perfectly modeled). Can you then 'invert' that to find the way of applying the current such that it travels exactly in the way you intended it to? The intention here is that if in theory you could perfectly control the behavior of the current or wave, obviously more precise control of biological tissue would be enabled, rather than the current methods which seem to imprecisely affect entire brain regions. I apologize if I made any mistakes or this seems trivial, I am still coming to grips with some of these concepts.

Comment: @tobalt Power lines and cables aren't exactly the same thing as completing a circuit in someone's brain or applying a magnetic field to induce currents.

Comment: Agreed .The question title should be adjusted to reflect the narrow scope of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the conductivity tensor $\sigma(r)$ and have perfect control over the magnetic field $B(r,t)$, then **yes** you can use Maxwell equations to exactly determine the field profile to generate the wanted currents.

In practice, you don't have sufficient control of the magnetic field, because you generate it from the far field, so you lack the necessary "resolution" $B(r)$